# Woocommerce in stock Notifier Api

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

i am using in stock notifier plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/back-in-stock-notifier-for-woocommerce/
in this plugin rest api or plugin of rest api not given
i am making custom rest api plugin and insert data in a table but email not coming during subscription of email id
and during in stock of product.
my custom code for instock api

```
 <?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Very First Plugin
* Plugin URI: https://www.yourwebsiteurl.com/
* Description: This is the very first plugin I ever created.
* Version: 1.0
* Author: Your Name Here
* Author URI: http://yourwebsiteurl.com/
**/





    
    /**
     * Grab latest post title by an author!
     *
     * @param array $data Options for the function.
     * @return string|null Post title for the latest,          * or null if none.
     */
    /*
    function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
      $posts = get_posts( array(
        'author' => $data['id'],
      ) );
     
      if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
        return null;
      }
     
      return $posts[0]->post_title;
    }
    
    
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
      register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/authorsss/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
      ) );
    } );
    */
    
    
    function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
    
    global $wpdb;
    
    
    
    
    if($data['cwginstock_user_id']==''){
    
     $students_arr = array(
                    "responseCode" =>  400,
                    "responseMessage" => "Please enter user id.",);
                echo json_encode($students_arr);
    
    }elseif($data['cwginstock_subscriber_email'] == ''){
    
     $students_arr = array(
                    "responseCode" =>400,
                    "responseMessage" =>  "Please enter email id.",);
                echo json_encode($students_arr);
    
    
    }elseif($data['cwginstock_pid'] == ''){
    
     $students_arr = array(
                    "responseCode" =>400,
                    "responseMessage" =>  "Please enter product id.",);
                echo json_encode($students_arr);
    
    
    }else{
    
    
    $tablename2 = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
    
    
    //himanshu-swamiitechs-co-in__trashed
     $ok =  str_replace(".","",$data['cwginstock_subscriber_email']);
     $post_name =  str_replace("@","-",$ok);
    
    
    
    $res = $wpdb->insert(
                    $tablename2,
                    array(
                       'post_author' => $data['cwginstock_user_id'],
                       'post_content' => "",
                       'post_title' => $data['cwginstock_subscriber_email'],
                       'post_excerpt' => "",
                       'post_name'=>$post_name,
                       'post_status' =>'cwg_subscribed',
                       'comment_status' => 'closed',
                       'ping_status' => 'closed',
                       'post_password' => "",
                       'to_ping' => "",
                       'pinged' => "",
                       'post_content_filtered' =>'',
                       'post_parent' =>'',
                       //'guid' => 'http://localhost/ecommerces4/cwginstocknotifier/himanshu-swamiitechs-co-in/',
                       'guid' => 'http://localhost/ecommerces4/cwginstocknotifier/'.$post_name.'/',
                       "menu_order"=> 0,
                       "post_type"=> "cwginstocknotifier",
                       "post_mime_type" =>"",
                       "comment_count"=> 0,
                       "post_date"=>Date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                       "post_date_gmt"=>Date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                       "post_modified_gmt" =>Date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                       "post_modified"=>Date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                   )
                );
    
    
    $lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
    
    
    
    
    
    
    $data1 = array(
            'cwginstock_variation_id',
             'cwginstock_subscriber_email',
              'cwginstock_user_id',
               'cwginstock_language',
               'cwginstock_pid' 
        );
    $data3 = array(0, $data['cwginstock_subscriber_email'],
               $data['cwginstock_user_id'], "en_US",$data['cwginstock_pid']
        );
    
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta";
    foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) {
    $res = $wpdb->insert(
                    $tablename,
                    array(
                       'post_id' => $lastid,
                        'meta_key' => $value,
                        'meta_value' => $data3[$key]
                   )
                );
    }
    
    if($res){
            echo 'inserted';
        }else{
            echo 'not inserted';
        }
    
    return $wpdb;
    }
    }
    
    
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        $namespace = 'myplugin/v1';
         $endpoint = '/authorsss/';
      register_rest_route( $namespace, $endpoint, array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func'
      ) );
    } );
```

i want to proper insert data in database, email alert is not coming and
in admin side in plugin product name not showing even i am sending product id

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing. I used your code as a base to start but changed some small things and it works now.

```
//himanshu-swamiitechs-co-in__trashed
    $ok =  str_replace(".","-",$data['cwginstock_subscriber_email']);
    $post_name =  str_replace("@","",$ok);
```

the str_replace needed to be different. replace . by - and remove @

```
$data1 = array(
        'cwginstock_product_id' ,
        'cwginstock_variation_id',
         'cwginstock_subscriber_email',
        'cwginstock_user_id',
        'cwginstock_language',
           'cwginstock_pid' ,
    );
```

Secondly this is the right order and variables

Underneath you can see the whole code I used

```
function back_in_stock_email ( $data) {
   // Get request params
    
    global $wpdb;

    if ($data['cwginstock_user_id']=='') {
    
        $students_arr = array(
            "responseCode" =>  400,
            "responseMessage" => "Please enter user id.",);
            echo json_encode($students_arr);
    
    } elseif ($data['cwginstock_subscriber_email'] == '') {
    
        $students_arr = array(
            "responseCode" =>400,
            "responseMessage" =>  "Please enter email id.",);
            echo json_encode($students_arr);
    
    
    } elseif($data['cwginstock_pid'] == '') {
    
        $students_arr = array(
            "responseCode" =>400,
            "responseMessage" =>  "Please enter product id.",);
            echo json_encode($students_arr);
    } else {
        $tablename2 = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
    
        //himanshu-swamiitechs-co-in__trashed
        $ok =  str_replace(".","-",$data['cwginstock_subscriber_email']);
        $post_name =  str_replace("@","",$ok);

        $res = $wpdb->insert(
            $tablename2,
            array(
                'post_author' => "0",
                'post_content' => "",
                'post_title' => $data['cwginstock_subscriber_email'],
                'post_excerpt' => "",
                'post_name'=>$post_name,
                'post_status' =>'cwg_subscribed',
                'comment_status' => 'closed',
                'ping_status' => 'closed',
                'post_password' => "",
                'to_ping' => "",
                'pinged' => "",
                'post_content_filtered' =>'',
                'post_parent' =>'',
                'guid' => '<YOUR BASE URL>/cwgstocknotifier/'.$post_name.'/',
                "menu_order"=> "0",
                "post_type"=> "cwginstocknotifier",
                "post_mime_type" =>"",
                "comment_count"=> "0",
                "post_date"=>Date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                "post_date_gmt"=>Date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                "post_modified_gmt" =>Date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                "post_modified"=>Date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            )
        );

        $lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
        echo $lastid;

        $data1 = array(
            'cwginstock_product_id' ,
            'cwginstock_variation_id',
             'cwginstock_subscriber_email',
            'cwginstock_user_id',
            'cwginstock_language',
               'cwginstock_pid' ,
        );
        $data3 = array($data['cwginstock_pid'], $data['cwginstock_variation_id'], 
        $data['cwginstock_subscriber_email'], "0","en_US",$data['cwginstock_pid']);
    
        $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta";
        foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) {
            $res = $wpdb->insert(
                $tablename,
                array(
                    'post_id' => $lastid,
                    'meta_key' => $value,
                    'meta_value' => $data3[$key]
                )
            );
        }
    
        if ($res) {
            echo 'inserted';
        } else {
            echo 'not inserted';
        }
    return $wpdb;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you highlight the changes you did and help guide OP to the resolution. Code only answers do not help OP and others to know how to resolve the issue